# How to find Google Photo Sphere PanoId

Tags: google-photos

I'm having hard time to find `panoid`as described on [this page](https://developers.google.com/photo-sphere/web/). It says that when you click share button you'll see iframe code there and it contains panoid but there is no iframe embed code. I guess google disabled iframe embedding. So is there another way to get PanoID. It is a string similar to this one `9SQgZnQdRXVQHMtBHZtnNg`

https://developers.google.com/photo-sphere/web/

Answer (score 0):

If you go to http://maps.google.com/views, and you click on your profile and one of your photo spheres there, you will find the share button on the right-hand side. When you hit it, you should see the option "Embed this image", which contains the iframe snipped the developers page is talking about.